# How do I show a button within my thread here? java android

Tags: java, android, button, visibility

I've been trying to make a button visible when the `counter == 7` but it just keeps crashing whenever I add a method `showButton()`.

This is the method that makes the button visible:

```
public void showButton() {
    b.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

While this is where the thread starts and animates, tho it keeps crashing whenever the counter reaches 7.

```
void animateFace() {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                counter++;
                if (counter > 8)
                    counter = 0;
                if (counter == 1)
                    facedest8 = facedest1;
                if (counter == 2)
                    facedest9 = facedest2;
                if (counter == 3)
                    facedest10 = facedest3;
                if (counter == 4)
                    facedest11 = facedest4;
                if (counter == 5)
                    facedest12 = facedest5;
                if (counter == 6)
                    facedest13 = facedest6;
                if (counter == 7)
                    facedest14 = facedest7;
                showButton();
                SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't show anything in the log, it just crashes..

Comment: make sure that button is not null

Comment: It's not. The idea behind it is for me to be able to onClick on this button so that it leads to another page once my splash screen is finished..

Comment: Try runOnUiThread() method as you are trying to update UI from different thread

Answer (score 0):

UI updates should be done on the main thread. Try this:

```
public void showButton() {
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
});
}
```

To display the button after an 8 sec delay, you can do this:

```
public void animateFace() {
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
  }
}, 8000);
// No need to call showButton() anywhere in this case
}
```

Comment: You dont need to put anything in the main thread. The handler does that for you. Replace your showButton() method with the above code and see if that works.

Comment: It doesn't work.. Can I just ask you something different? I want to delay the visibility of my button for like 8 seconds.. That way, it can be able to display it parallel to the time that the thread finishes in my canvas.. I'm also gonna do it on my main activity so that it won't affect the Thread inside my canvas.. Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can basically call the postDelayed() method on the handler providing the delay you want before the run method executes.

Comment: Last question dude, it doesn't seem to do anything cause I didn't call this method, showButton(), anywhere. Where should I put it?

Comment: To make things very simple, you just want to make the button visible after the 8 second delay right? Then, replace your entire animateFace method code with the handler.postDelayed() code I just added. You do not have to call showButton() in that case.

Answer (score 0):

if showButton() is part of activity, then,

```
  public void showButton() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
    });
  }
```

if showButton() is outside activity then pass reference of activity to showButton(),

```
  public void showButton(Activity context) {
    context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      }
    });

  }
```